# Django - mark only certain part of string / user input as safe?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

The user text input is as follows:

```
Test 'post'. Post at 8:52 on Feb 3rd. /u/username created it.
This <a href="link">link</a> should not be displayed as a link.
```

I send the user's input through a custom filter when showing it on the template. This is the custom filter:

```
word_split_re = re.compile(r'(\s+)')

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def customUrlize(value):
    words = word_split_re.split(force_text(value))
    for i, b in enumerate(words):
        if b.startswith('/u/'):
            username = b[3:]
            if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$", username):
                b = "<a href='testLink'>" + b + "</a>"
                words[i] = mark_safe(b)
    return ''.join(words)
```

As you can see, what I want to do is wrap the words which start with '/u/' (And only contains letters, numbers, underscores and dashes) with an

```
<a>
```

tag. With the current filter, all the code is escaped and it is displayed as:

```
Test 'post'. Post at 8:52 on Feb 3rd. <a href='testLink'>/u/username</a> created it.
This <a href="link">link</a> should not be displayed as a link.
```

What I want is for the text to be displayed normally but for /u/username to be a link.

If I try doing:

```
return mark_safe(''.join(words))
```

then it displays even the

```
<a href="link">link</a>
```

as a link along with

```
/u/username
```

How do I make it so that it only displays

```
/u/username
```

as a link?

Edit: I am using Django 1.5.

In my template, assuming

```
comment
```

is a

```
CharField
```

I display the comment as so:

```
{{ comment|customUrlize }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is some additional formatting in the text that you want to keep, you can just [`escape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape) the text before altering it.

> Returns the given text with ampersands, quotes and angle brackets encoded for use in HTML. The input is first passed through `force_text()` and the output has `mark_safe()` applied.
>
> [<sup>From the Django documentation</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/)

So this line:

```
words = word_split_re.split(force_text(value))
```

Becomes this:

```
words = word_split_re.split(escape(value))
```

The complete filter is:

```
from django.utils.html import escape

word_split_re = re.compile(r'(\s+)')

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def customUrlize(value):
    words = word_split_re.split(escape(value)) 
    for i, b in enumerate(words):
        if b.startswith('/u/'):
            username = b[3:]
            if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$", username):
                b = "<a href='testLink'>" + b + "</a>"
                words[i] = mark_safe(b)
    return mark_safe(''.join(words))
```

And should give:

```
Test 'post'. Post at 8:52 on Feb 3rd. <a href='testLink'>/u/username</a> created it.
This &lt;a href="link"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt; should not be displayed as a link.
```

Which renders as:

> Test 'post'. Post at 8:52 on Feb 3rd. [/u/username](http://testLink) created it.
> This <a href="link">link</a> should not be displayed as a link.

Comment: hm, can you confirm again that the rendered text you displayed is exactly what it is rendered as for you? I copy-pasted your filter but for me it still renders "<a href='testLink'>/u/username</a>" and not an actual link. It seems as if Django escapes the text automatically as well even after my custom filter is applied. I'm using Django 1.5 if that helps.

Comment: Thats what should be rendered, I don't understand the problem. If its not escaping the `<` its working as intended?

Comment: the rendered text appears like this for me: "Test 'post'. Post at 8:52 on Feb 3rd. <a href='testLink'>/u/username</a> created it. This &lt;a href="link"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt; should not be displayed as a link."

I was hoping for "<a href='testLink'>/u/username</a>" to be rendered as an actual link rather than it displaying "<a href='testLink'>" in the html. Does what I am saying make more sense now?

Comment: Also, sorry, what I meant in my initial comment when I said "it still renders "<a href='testLink'>/u/username</a>"  was "it still gets rendered as "<a href='testLink'>/u/username</a>"

Comment: Not even remotely. It sounds like it is displaying a link.

Comment: it's not displaying a link. When I run the django sever and look at the what is displayed in the browser, I can see the actual Letters and symbols on the screen (by letters and symbols, I mean that I can see <a href='testLink'>/u/username </a> on my browser). it's not a clickable link, it's plain text. I was hoping for it to be a clickable link.

Comment: Ah... ok I see the issue, I wasn't diligent enough with the original template_tag. The `return` statement includes a string manipulation which removes the "safe" flag. Marking that returned string as safe should now work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it won't help depending on your needs, but you could just split the string in two and in the template mark only the first one with |safe.

For example:

```
a = "Test 'post'. Post at 8:52 on Feb 3rd. <a href='testLink'>/u/username</a> created it. This <a href='link'>link</a> should not be displayed as a link."

b = a.split('it.')
```

Then just pass it to the template as

```
'string1': b[0]
'string2': b[1]
```

or whatever, and then `{{string1|safe}} <br> {{string2}}` in the template.

The output will be as you wanted. Without the "it.", ofcourse. But that's easy to fix.